# Simple web service development with Eclipse/Tomcat for deployment to Websphere 6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, websphere

I've been working with web services in .NET for years, but am new to java-based web services.  I have some background working on web applications (struts, faces), but it's been a few years.  I need to develop a set of web services which will be deployed to Websphere 6.1 (Java SDK 1.5).  Ideally, I'd like to develop using Eclipse (Indigo SR 1 - Java EE) and test in Tomcat (Tomcat 6).  I'm familiar with these tools and have them installed.  I'm planning on starting with the contract (WSDL) which I've written in Eclipse.

Where should I go from here?  I think I need to somehow generate POJOs with JSR 181 annotations.  How do I generate them from Eclipse (or should I use a different tool)?  What needs to happen so that Tomcat and Websphere will discover the web service classes in my WAR and make them available as web services?

I was hoping to find a tutorial to walk me through this, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.  I suspect that there are many ways to do this.  I'm looking for an approach that will work well in Websphere 6.1 (Java 1.5) but will be easy to develop in Eclipse using Tomcat.

Comment: You might want to follow the tutorial 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.webservices.doc/tutorial/twvinboundws.htm